# How to organize python files, so that importing does not give ImportError:?

Tags: python, module

This question has been asked a million times. However none of the answers seems to be able to solve my problem.

I have a python module, with some scripts embedded in a c++ project.
I have the following folder structure:

```
mcmpy/
  setup.py
  doc/
  mcm/
    __init__.py
    cpp/
      __init__.py
      kindyn.py
    demos/
      __init__.py
      importer.py
```

in importer.py I tried, and does not work :

- from mcmpy.mcm.cpp import kindyn
- from mcm.cpp import kindyn
- from .cpp import kindyn
- from ..cpp import kindyn

What I want to achieve is to have some scripts in demo folder, and be able to run them from terminal with python3 *script_name*.py

Comment: Is it just a typo that you have `kyndin.py` in the files, and reference kindyn in the notes on importer.py?

Comment: edited it, yes it was a typo

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `__init__.py` file inside mcmpy/

```
mcmpy/
  __init__.py
  setup.py
  doc/
  mcm/
    __init__.py
    cpp/
      __init__.py
      kindyn.py
    demos/
      __init__.py
      importer.py
```

And inside the mcmpy folder, you just need to

```
from mcm.cpp import kindyn
```

Comment: I get an error if I do it :  "from mcmpy.mcm.cpp import kindyn
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mcmpy'"

Comment: from inside mcmpy directory

Comment: so try this: from mcm.cpp import kindyn

Comment: same result, this might work for you, because the IDE might set environment variables when executing it, it also works for me when run with CLion, not with terminal however

Comment: I tried now with the terminal, I simulated your folders and it works. Are you using which OS? Can you please check if there are any typos remaining?

Comment: python 3.5, Ubuntu 18 and 16, I am confused, I replicated the structure and does not work, which is your system?

Comment: can you please clone this? just run a python3 run.py and tell me what you have.
https://github.com/gpspelle/stackoverflow

Comment: I am using ubuntu 20.04 and python 3.8.3

Comment: this works, it is a bit different though, because the script is "above" the module folder, but anyway this is a possible solution

Comment: @zpasztor can you please make a git pull and check the newest version? If it solves your problem, don't hesitate to thumbs up :)

Answer (score 0):

To import with `from mcmpy.mcm.cpp import kindyn` you will need to install this project - `pip install -e <path of mcmpy>`.